# Glass deck above basement addition

Tags: basement, roof, deck, patio, glass

We're planning to expand our basement underneath our deck and would ideally like to cover this section of the deck in glass as in this photo.  (Posted: Wear skirts at your own risk!)

[image: Photo]

Our architect figures it would cost about $75k for the glass and supports alone, to do a similarly sized implementation in our home.  The interior dimensions are about 15'X 9' Do others agree with this estimate, or is there was perhaps a cost-saving measure that our architect might not have thought of.

Otherwise we'll be stuck with just a few glass panels at ~$3k each.

Comment: Can I come do that job for you? I could retire after building your deck... ...how much weight does that architect figure such a glass deck would hold before collapsing?

Comment: There's a boat load of construction details that have to keep out water and look good...all while getting walked on and not being so slick after a rain as to create a hazard. $555 per square foot for that type of construction doesn't seem implausible as an Architect's opinion of probable construction cost.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about costs of a job, not DIY home improvement.

Comment: Cost-savings and glass roof = leakage...

Comment: I want one...that looks awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Smells high, but hard to be sure. Older and presumably less expensive implementations seen under sidewalks use more of a concrete grid with small pieces of frosted glass - better relative strength and modesty preserved, but no stargazing from the basement. And, if the glass was broken (it's usually quite robust) there's no chance of people falling through it, given the much tighter support grid.

I'd imagine the sort of thing pictured is done on a one-off basis, so you have to pay for the engineering to your specific application, and the materials. And probably someone's liability insurance on the thing.

Comment: In addition to our architect, I ran this by a couple of companies that manufacture the glass that would be used for such a project.  They concurred that 75k to 100k is about what it would cost to do so, as hard as it may be to believe.